# Notification Content Extension not working in MacOs

Tags: macos, notification-content-extension

I've set up a Notification Content Extension for my app, but it's not getting called(tried both local and remote push). I've read the Apple dev guide, and I've set up everything as it says.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications

I've looked over the common issues (setting proper deployment targets and setting category identifiers from the backend and in the .plist)

After receiving the notification, I'm not able to get the expanded view and neither is the `didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification)` of my extension view controller getting invoked. Is there something I'm missing while doing the extension setup?